# uint8_t rollover in Python? What is the best or most elegant way?

Tags: python, c, rollover, uint8t

in C, I can do the following:

```
uint8_t number;
number++;
```

Note: If the number is >255, then is rolls over to 0.

How can I do it Python?

```
number += 1
if number>255:
    number = 0
```

This looks for me not the optimal or pythonic way.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can freely do all standard mathematic operations and whenever you need the output in byte range just use `number % 256` instead of the `number`. Or you can extend this approach to a class and define all standard operators (`__add__()`, `__neg__()`,...) there.  Or you can use `c_ubyte` datatype from [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

Python provides [arbitrary sized integers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex). There is one integer type that can accommodate integers of any size.

You can avoid the if statement by using mod 256 after the increment.

```
number = (number + 1) % 256
```

Comment: a good idea:
could be also:
number = (number + 1) & 0xFF

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module for this, which provides the datatypes that are present in c.

```
from ctypes import *
a=c_uint8(255)
b=c_uint(1)
c=c_uint8(a.value + b.value)
print(a, b, c)
```

OUTPUT

```
(c_ubyte(255), c_ulong(1L), c_ubyte(0))
```